# ranking one column on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I have a table of the form:

```
userid  rank  name
-------------------
1       4     raj
1       90    frank
1       100   neeta
1       123   liz
2       2     liz
2       20    neeta
2       23    frank
2       222   raj
```

I need to convert this into

```
userid  min_rank  next_min_rank
-------------------------------
1       raj       frank
2       liz       neeta
```

I have been searching the net for this issue for a long time but could not find a solution.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will select the minimun rank, and the next rank for every user:

```
select s.userid, s.min_rank, min(users.rank) as next_rank
from (
  select userid, min(rank) as min_rank
  from users
  group by userid) s left join users
  on users.userid = s.userid and s.min_rank<users.rank
group by s.userid
```

ant this will show the names:

```
select t.userid, t1.name, t2.name
from (
  select s.userid, s.min_rank, min(users.rank) as next_rank
  from (
    select userid, min(rank) as min_rank
    from users
    group by userid) s left join users
    on users.userid = s.userid and s.min_rank<users.rank
  group by s.userid ) t
  left join users t1 on t.userid=t1.userid and t.min_rank=t1.rank
  left join users t2 on t.userid=t2.userid and t.next_rank=t2.rank
```

The result is:

```
1  raj  frank
2  liz  neeta
```

If there could be more than one user with the same rank, it depends on how you want to handle the situation, you might just add this:

```
group by t.userid
```

to show just one of them. Maybe you could also use `GROUP_CONCAT(t1.name), GROUP_CONACT(t2.name)` on the select.

Comment: I was thinking the same on `GROUP_CONCAT()` when I was writing. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegent one. But give it a try.

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7586f/3)

Query:

```
select b.userid, x.name1, b.name  as name2
from ranks b
join 
(
select a.userid, min(a.rank), a.name as name1
      from ranks a
      group by a.userid
) as x
on x.userid = b.userid
where (b.userid, b.rank, b.name) not in
(
select a.userid, min(a.rank), a.name
      from ranks a
      group by a.userid
)
group by b.userid
;
```

Results:

```
USERID  NAME1   NAME2
1       raj     frank
2       liz     neeta
```

Comment: @Rahul +1 for the interesting question. check this answer out and please comment for any ideas and improvements ;)

Answer (score 1):

This did work for me with same data

```
SELECT  N1.USERID AS USERID,N1.NAME AS MIN_RANK, N2.NAME AS NEXT_RANK 
FROM (SELECT USERID,NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE RANK IN(SELECT  Min(Table1.rank) AS MinOfrank FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.UserID))  N1,
(SELECT USERID,NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE RANK IN (SELECT Min(RANK) AS Expr1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE (TABLE1.rank) Not In (SELECT MIN(RANK) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY USERID)  GROUP BY USERID))  N2 
WHERE
N1.USERID=N2.USERID;
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.userid , a.name minRank, 
       (select name from usertable where userid =a.userid and rank>a.rank 
        order by rank limit 1) nextMinRank
From (Select userid, name ,rank from usertable order by rank) as a
Group by userid, rank
```

Comment: doesnt work the way i wanted to be. I need user id to be distinct in my case.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `ORDER BY` inside the derived table (`a`)?

Comment: Because if table contains rank value 4 than 15 than 2 for userid 3 than group by not work properit selects rank 4 not 2 so i have used order by in my query